# Proxy request host is overwritten by the real request

Tags: go, proxy, server

I am trying to serve a proxy like this:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        println(r.Host)
    }))
}
```

and calling it with curl

`curl -k -x http://localhost:8080 http://golang.org/`

I get `golang.org` printed out. Why I do not get the proxy hostname `localhost`? is that a bug or limitation with the http proxy?

## Update

To clarify, what I am looking for is something like Nginx server address http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_addr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use LocalAddrContextKey but looks like there is a known bug with setting it https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18686
A workaround is to hijack the `http.ResponseWriter` ex:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        hij, ok := w.(http.Hijacker)
        if !ok {
            panic("http server does not support hijacker")
        }

        clientConn, _, err := hij.Hijack()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        println(clientConn.LocalAddr().String())

    }))
}
```